# Django - Migrate a model field from float to an array of float

Tags: django, postgresql, migration

I have a postgres databse in a Django application.

We designed a database and started to populate it on production. However it appears that one of the field on one of our model is supposed to be an Array of float instead of a float.

To do so I'd like to use the ArrayField from postgres. But if I juste replace my `models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Space between nozzles'))` by `models.ArrayField(models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Space between nozzles')))` I got this error when I try to migrate:

> cannot cast type double precision to double precision[]

Can I convert my model field type this easily ?

Thanks

Comment: you would have to delete all previous data , then try again. If there is still error, delete all migrations in the migrations.py file and then do make  migrations and migrate it again

Comment: Yes, This is know but I was wondering if there was a way to do this without losing my data in production. I feel like this is possible because it would just need to append a value of the same type in a array